# Two Pakyow servers simultaneously

Tags: pakyow

I have been developing two different Pakyow webapps. When I run one of the apps locally with the command `pakyow server`, it is available at `tcp://0.0.0.0:3000/`. However, if I try to run both apps simultaneously, the second one started throws (from `binder.rb`) the error `Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)`.

Clearly I cannot use the same port for both apps, but I do not know how to run the second app on a different port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-p` flag to start an app on a specific port. For example:

```
pakyow server -p 3001
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @bryanp said, you can also add

```
server.port = 3001
```

to your `app/setup.rb` file if you don't want to worry about passing an argument each launch.

Comment: This is nice. It'll save me from having to recall the flag usage each time!